# Return a Boolean instead of a string containing True or False in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean

I have a small problem with `True` or `False` Boolean.

I have Defined a procedure `weekend` which takes a string as its input, and returns the Boolean `True if 'Saturday' or 'Sunday'` and `False` otherwise.

Here is my `weekend` function:

```
def weekend(day):
    if day == 'Saturday' or day == 'Sunday':
        return "True"
    else:
        return "False"
```

Here is my output:

```
>>>print weekend('Monday')
False
>>>print weekend('Saturday')
True
>>>print weekend('July')
False
```

But as you see in my code, I'm returning a **string** BUT I want to return a **Boolean** `True or False`.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Just get rid of the quotes around `"True"` / `"False"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
def weekend(day):
    if day == 'Saturday' or day == 'Sunday':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Or this:

```
def weekend(day):
    return day == 'Saturday' or day == 'Sunday'
```

Or even simpler:

```
def weekend(day):
    return day in ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

Anyway: in Python the boolean values are `True` and `False`, without quotes - but also know that there exist several *falsy* values - that is, values that behave exactly like `False` if used in a condition. For example: `""`, `[]`, `None`, `{}`, `0`, `()`.

Comment: And of course `0.` is also falsy (not to mention `0j` and `0L`).

Answer (score 2):

This is the shortest way to write the function and output a boolean

```
def weekend(day):
    return day == 'Saturday' or day == 'Sunday'
```

or

```
def weekend(day):
    return day in ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was using `"` marks around `True`, remove those and it will work.  Here are some more pythonic ways to write this method:

```
def weekend(day):
    if day.lower() in ('saturday', 'sunday'):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Using `.lower()` when checking is a good way to ignore case.  You can also use the `in` statement to see if the string is found in a list of strings

Here is a super short way

```
def weekend(day):
  return day.lower() in ('saturday', 'sunday')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def weekend(day):
    if day == 'Saturday' or day == 'Sunday':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

you are doing return "True" and return "False" which make it a string rather than Boolean

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a Boolean instead of a String just get rid of the quotes `''` around True and False.

Try This:

```
def weekend(day):
    """ Return True if day is Saturday or Sunday otherwise False."""

    return day in ('saturday', 'sunday'):
```

or as the others before me have said:

```
def weekend(day):
    """ Return True if day is Saturday or Sunday otherwise False."""

    return day == 'Saturday' or day == 'Sunday'
```